# dotnet core 3.0 SSL works in debug mode but not with `dotnet run`

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core, https, kestrel

I got this weird issue after upgrading to dotnet Core 3.0 -
When running an MVC app in debug mode (VSCode F5), everything works fine i.e. I can browse my site using https with the dev certificate (and also with a trusted self-signed certificate).

However, when using `dotnet run`, the application starts normally, saying it is listening on https://localhost:5001, but when I try to access the page, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` error.

The log shows the following message:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware[1]
      Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection.
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
 ---> Interop+AppleCrypto+SslException: Internal error
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsServer(SslServerAuthenticationOptions sslServerAuthenticationOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsServerAsync>b__69_0(SslServerAuthenticationOptions arg1, CancellationToken arg2, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsServerAsync(SslServerAuthenticationOptions sslServerAuthenticationOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware.InnerOnConnectionAsync(ConnectionContext context)
```

This is on macOS Catalina 10.15. Note the `Interop+AppleCrypto+SslException`

Any ideas?

Assaf